# Formatting matrices in Word document

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, word-wrap, .doc

I have 5 matrices that I need to multiply. If I put them side to side in a line in Word, about 3 of them will be missing as they exceed the A4 size. I want to format them in such a way that once they get to the margin, they will automatically enter the next line so that all the matrices will appear.

I tried to adjust the size of the paper but it did not work.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.